# Rails Globalize3 column sizes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins, globalize2

How do you specify the column size of the columns in the translation tables?

From the README:

```
Post.create_translation_table! :title => :string, :text => :text
```

how would I work in a :limit => 37337?

I tried

```
Post.create_translation_table! :title => :string, :limit => 1000, :text => :text
```

but that doesn't work

using rails 3 + globalize3 0.1.0.beta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post.create_translation_table! :title =>{ :type=> :string, :limit => 1000}, :text => :text